# OpenCV drawContours always draws in white

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to draw contours I got from cv2.threshold in random colors.
This is my code.

```
    for c in contours:
        color = list(np.random.rand(3)*255)
        color = [int(color[0]), int(color[1]), int(color[2])]
        #color = [255, 0,0]
        cv2.drawContours(mosaic, [c], 0, color, 3)
```

But the contours are always drawn in white. And no, my image is not grayscale because when i uncomment the `color = [255, 0,0]` line the contours are drawn in blue (or any other color) and when i do something like `color[1] += 20` each iteration the colors are modified as expected. It's only when i use my code that it's drawn in white. The variable color, when printed, outputs a list of [b,g,r] values as expected. I tried messing with different data types, using tuples, np arrays instead of lists but to no avail.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to change the seed value for random values each iteration or else it draws the same colors each iteration. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html

Comment: Good idea but no. I checked the output. All of the colors are different and none of them are white.

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example? It will be easier to help you

Comment: your presented usage of np.random is acceptable. no need to change it. -- sorry but *no*, do NOT set the seed value in the loop. that's not how any of that works.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The image was float64 which i'm guessing has a lower possible range of values in opencv so when i passed it something like [120, 100, 90] it was out of range and drew it as white. I set it to uint8 and now it works.
Still doesn't explain why it would draw colors properly when something like [255, 0, 0] was passed.

Comment: Ohh if opencv interprets float64 in range [0,1] passing [255, 0, 0] would only blow out the blue channel.